# Openlayers 3 equivalent of render intents of OpenLayers.Stylemap?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openlayers, style, events

I want to convert my openlayers 2 features to openlayers 3. I have following part in openlayers 2. I need an equivalent of StyleMap in openlayers 3 so that I can distinguish the default action and select action.

```
var subMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
        fillColor:"orange",
        strokeColor:"orange"
    }),
    "select": new OpenLayers.Style({
        fillColor:"#00FFFF",
        strokeColor:"#00FFFF"
    })
});
```

I can write the following for "default" case. But where to mention for the "select" case?

```
var subMap= new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: "orange"
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color:"orange"
    })
});
```

Can anyone please help in this regard?

Comment: Waiting for answers.

Comment: Could you provide some code snippet of your current style?

Comment: @juminet I have given the code snippet in the question. That is the style. One for "default" and another for "select". How to write it in openlayers 3?

Comment: @juminet Ok, edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenLayers 3 (or 4), features selection is handled by an interaction. The relevant doc about selection is here: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html

Here's a piece of code that allows to select any features in your map, and to apply a special style to it (`styleSelect`):

```
  // render selected features with a red stroke
  var styleSelect =  new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'red',
        width: 2
      })
  });

  // a normal select interaction to handle click
  var select = new ol.interaction.Select({style: styleSelect});
  map.addInteraction(select);
```

The default (not selected) style can be defined elsewhere, using another `ol.style.Style` object.