# Dynamic styles in OpenLayers 3 : Again

Tags: openlayers

Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655662/dynamic-styles-in-openlayers-3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251893/how-to-dynamically-style-cluster-layer-without-style-function.

I have a Vector layer with some features I load from a server in GeoJSON format.

```
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();

    var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures( featuresObj , {
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
    });

    for ( var i = 0; i < features.length; i++ ) {
        features[i].setStyle( defaultStyle );   // <<<< --- apply the default style
        vectorSource.addFeature( features[i] );
    }          

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
    });
```

As you can see I apply a default style to it.
The default style must have some attribute based configuration like:

```
new ol.style.Style({
       fill: new ol.style.Fill({
           color: ${fillColor},
       }),
       stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
           color: ${strokeColor},
           width: 1,
       })
});
```

This worked nice until OL2.

Now you say "Yo man, just use the style function `function(feature, resolution)` and use each `feature` attribute in the style! Bind it to the `vectorLayer`..."

Here comes the problem....

I have a `default` style because I need other styles to be applied to the features later. I have to switch styles between `default` and `selected` when the user clicks on each feature to hilight them.

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
map.addInteraction(select);

select.on('select', function(event) {
    var selected = event.selected;
    var deselected = event.deselected;

    selected.forEach(function(feature){
          feature.setStyle( selectedStyle );
    });

    deselected.forEach(function(feature){
          feature.setStyle( defaultStyle );
    });                

});
```

I need to keep both styles dynamic because I'll not use the styles function anymore until I reload the entire layer.

I think removing the "${attribute_name}" dynamic value was a step back from the OL guys...

How can I do what I need?

Comment: Can't you use interaction? See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253801/openlayers-3-equivalent-of-render-intents-of-openlayers-stylemap/254044#254044

Comment: How can this help me? Please read carefully my question...